# Expo Running on android emulator on a mac

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

I have followed all of the steps [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/android-studio-emulator/?redirected) and I can successfully run adb on my terminal. When I do expo start, the cli gives me the following messages: 
[image: This Image]

But when I click on run on Androidd I get the following message: 
[image]

which bothers me a little because the error says that it is not able to run adb but 2 lines above the messages says it successfully ran 'adb reverse',

any suggestions on what to do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it after running your android emulator first.
It happens to me too.

Comment: I have tried running it and running 2 at a time, i have tried different emulators